# Is there any way to map keys for hiding and showing bottom bar in Zathura?

Tags: linux, unix, pdf, zathura

I want to map keys so that pressing a button hides the bar in statusbar.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> is working but I want to map it to another key.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to map `b` key for this
use this

```
map b toggle_statusbar
```

by pressing `b` it will show and hide the statusbar in zathura